# .NET 4, writing a windows service for logging and directory monitoring

Tags: .net, logging, windows-services

I've written a software as a windows **console application**; there's a config file that specifies how to log in the  section.

Now that I've tested it and it works fine, I want to convert it into a windows service. I created a new project but I have two problems:

1) Logging doesn't seem to happen anymore; the config file is no more read, or logging can't happen for some other reason (permissions?). Anyway I was thinking what is the best way to log for a windows service, maybe through the windows event logging? And how? Or is it better to make my config file work so that I can disable logging without recompiling?

2) In the service I use a set of FileSystemWatcher objects to monitor directories. It looks like in the service I don't get the monitoring events anymore. Any hints?

Thanks

**edit:**
A step forward for point 2) - After debugging I've found that I get the events, the problem is that in the event I try to move a file with `File.Move` and it fails.

**edit2:**
Another little step forward for point 2) - I had to install the service with user permissions, otherwise it doens't let me move a file. This is solved.

Comment: Where is your log file stored? Yes, Windows Services run under a different permissions model. This is hard to diagnose without specific information about your configuration.

Comment: the output file you mean? it should go in the same dir where the service exe is (after compilation, but probabily during the service installation it is moved somewehere else).

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one question in your post.

One possible reason why you don't see logs you might be looking at the wrong place. Services are started with Current Working Directory as %systemroot%\system32, so it will try to create logs there.

Comment: yeah, but the log is not there. I suspect it doesn't even read the config file.

Comment: One quick way to find out if it is trying to write a log is by kicking off Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and looking at file system operations. If service runs as Network Service or using account of non-administrative user, it will fail to create file in system32 directory.

Comment: In addition to this, if your service process is 32 bit and OS is 64 bit, you might also check %systemroot%\Syswow64.